# snake game crashes after eating several times with TypeError variable undefined

Tags: javascript

It's been few days that I've been learning JavaScript. So I'm completely new to this.

This is my code for snake game and it isn't complete yet but I've run into a problem. I'm not completely sure that if it's a logical error or not.

After eating the food several times, the game crashes with

> TypeError: snakeBody[l] is undefined.

[Screenshot of the error is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqQ1w.png)

The entire code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style>
    canvas {
        background: #080d16;
        border: 5px solid green;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="mycan" class="mycan" width="1860" height="920"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycan');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var snakeSize = 20;
    var snakeX = 100;
    var snakeY = 100;
    var foodX = 310;
    var foodY = 310;
    var foodSize = 10;
    var dx = 20;
    var dy = 20;
    var leftPressed = false;
    var rightPressed = true;
    var topPressed = false;
    var bottomPressed = false;
    var snakeBody = [{x:snakeX,y:snakeY},{x:snakeX-20,y:snakeY}];
    var z = 0;



    //keypress event listner
    document.addEventListener('keypress', keyHandler, false);
    //keypress event handler function
    function keyHandler(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            leftPressed = true;
            rightPressed = false;
            topPressed = false;
            bottomPressed = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            leftPressed = false;
            rightPressed = false;
            topPressed = true;
            bottomPressed = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            leftPressed = false;
            rightPressed = true;
            topPressed = false;
            bottomPressed = false;
        } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            leftPressed = false;
            rightPressed = false;
            topPressed = false;
            bottomPressed = true;
        }
    }

    //draw food 
    function food() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(foodX, foodY, foodSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    //draw snake
    function snake() {
        for (var l = 0; l < snakeBody.length; l++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(snakeBody[l].x, snakeBody[l].y, snakeSize, snakeSize);
            if (l == 0) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        console.log(l);
        var head = {
            x: snakeX,
            y: snakeY
        };
        snakeBody.pop();
        snakeBody.unshift(head);

    }

    function tail() {
        if ((snakeX + dx / 2 > foodX - foodSize && snakeX + dx / 2 < foodX + foodSize) && (snakeY + dy / 2 > foodY - foodSize && snakeY + dy / 2 < foodY + foodSize)) {
            foodX = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 88) + 1) * 20 + 10;
            foodY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) + 1) * 20 + 10;
            z++;
            if (snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].x == snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 2].x && snakeBody[0].y < snakeBody[1].y) {
                snakeBody[z] = {
                    x: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].x,
                    y: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].y + 20
                };

            } else if (snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].x == snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 2].x && snakeBody[0].y > snakeBody[1].y) {
                snakeBody[z] = {
                    x: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].x,
                    y: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].y - 20
                };
            } else if (snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].y == snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 2].y && snakeBody[0].x > snakeBody[1].x) {
                snakeBody[z] = {
                    x: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].x - 20,
                    y: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].y
                };
            } else if (snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].y == snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 2].y && snakeBody[0].x < snakeBody[1].x) {
                snakeBody[z] = {
                    x: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].x + 20,
                    y: snakeBody[snakeBody.length - 1].y
                };
            }
        }
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        snake();
        food();
        tail();

        if (rightPressed && snakeX + dx < canvas.width) {
            snakeX += dx;
        } else if (leftPressed && snakeX > 0) {
            snakeX += -dx;
        } else if (topPressed && snakeY > 0) {
            snakeY += -dy;
        } else if (bottomPressed && snakeY + dy < canvas.height) {
            snakeY += dy;
        }

    }

    setInterval(draw, 80);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in algorithm - your snakeBody put/pops elements and you miss some "corner cases" when use indexes in this array  - the problem is not with JS but with algorithm - debug it and also use "triangle" in chrome konsole on left side of error to see more details (stacktrace)

Answer (score 0):

I check and run your code more than once. This error does not appear for me. It is good for you to check the values in `snake` function and then use them. Modify your `snake` function to this

```
function snake() {
    for (var l = 0; l < snakeBody.length; l++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        if(snakeBody && snakeBody[l] && snakeBody[l].hasOwnProperty('x') && snakeBody[l].hasOwnProperty('y')) {
            ctx.rect(snakeBody[l].x, snakeBody[l].y, snakeSize, snakeSize);
        }
        if (l == 0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
        }
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();

    }
    console.log(l);
    var head = {
        x: snakeX,
        y: snakeY
    };
    snakeBody.pop();
    snakeBody.unshift(head);

}
```

As you can see, `snakeBody` has no indexes 24 and 25. But this condition satisfy this.

[image]